# Use new javamail version on XPages

Tags: osgi, xpages, jakarta-mail

I would use a new version of JavaMail in XPages.

Reading various posts only solution seems to be to make a plugin OSGI.

Building a plugin I get a "Class not found" exception

Someone has managed to create the plugin or the classloader XPages kills this way?

Answer (score 1):

For adding a third party jar into a plugin there are a few gotchas. John Dalsgaard has done a good blog on this http://www.dalsgaard-data.eu/blog/wrap-an-existing-jar-file-into-a-plug-in/. The slides from my session at ICON UK on OSGi plugins are also available, for which I packaged up a third-party jar http://www.slideshare.net/paulswithers1/from-xpages-hero-to-osgi-guru-taking-the-scary-out-of-building-extension-libraries-icon-uk-2014

Comment: Thanks for the nice words Paul ;-)  ... I guess you could circumvent the problem that Ferry mentions by wrapping it into your own plugin and give it another package name. Then I can't really see why it should not take your version :-)

Comment: I had already tried the step by step guide of John Dalsgaard. 

I have successfully installed the plugin on server 8.5.3 but I had a "Class not found" exception. "Tell HTTP OSGI ss ...." was ok 

To me that says Ferry could be founded. 

I'll try again

Comment: If the Domino server has the same plugin and version, it will be loaded from there. If the version number is higher (e.g. it has today's date), that should solve it. It's the same concept as used for adding different versions of Dojo to the server.

Comment: They are partially able to upload my plugin (it.myplug.test) on http and designers. 

I followed again the example of John Dalsgaard and installed everything on the server and designer 9.0.1 and enabled the plugin it.myplug.test.XspLibrary in the properties of my nsf 

From SSJS I can use for example it.myplug.test.XspLibrary () but if I go into debug jar javax.mail still see version 1.3 

The classes of the object should be automatically overwritten? or do I have to include a few different instruction? Or should I create new methods in XspLibrary?

Comment: How are you debugging? In Domino Designer, unless the source files are available, it's probably going to the only code it can see. I debug my plugins from Eclipse, using the Domino Debug Plugin. Niklas Heidloff's video is very straightforward http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dchOyzjy9L4 (You won't need the IBM Java install Niklas installs to debug your plugin)

Comment: I'm using the new plugin class directly from SSJS.

From SSJS I see my XspLibrary classes created in the plugin.
I don't see the new javax.mail classes, it still uses the build-in javamail.

However i try to use the jar classes into new method in Plugin XspLibrary. This is done.

In SSJS javax.mail.Session is 1.3.0 Into new plugin is 1.5.2.

I expected that the object javax.mail.Session was overwritten by the new version without having to use plugin

Answer (score 0):

I while ago I had the same question. I created an OSGi plugin and wrapped the latest Javamail jar inside it. It did 'work' because I could use this classes in Designer, but I found out that whenever server code excecutes, it still uses the build-in javamail. Probably because it was loaded earlier and because of that not overridable.

Probably the ugliest solution you can think of, but replacing the 'mail.jar' in the directory [domino]\osgi\shared\eclipse\plugins\com.ibm.designer.lib.javamail_9.0.0.20130301-1431\lib\ did and still works.

If you ever find a better solution, I really hope you could share it ;-)